# find multiple pattern from a string and return even pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see one coding question as following. what will be a better solution for it? I have tried using two while loop and wondering if there is better/ clean way to do it?

> One message system contains two device type message that each message is formatted with device type identifier with device id and message count. Write a function to parse the message based on device type and message count and return a list with each device id in even message frequency
>   rule: input string: message
>   device identifier
>   1:iOS device ID identifier: start with 'I' following with 3 character, total length is 4 character
>   2:Android device ID identifier: start with 'A' following with 2 character, total length is 3 character
>   3:message count is following by device id until next device ID
>
> ex: input: Asq2: {'Asq': 2} Asq with 2 message count
>   output: ['Asq', 'Asq']
>
> input: Akb2IAld3: ID: {'Akb': 2, 'IAld': 3} Akb with 2 message count, IAld with 3 message count
>   output: ['Akb', 'IAld', 'Akb', 'IAld', 'IAld']
>
> input: Aqp1Iasd10Aqp4IAbd1Iasd2: {'Aqp': 5, 'Iasd': 12, 'IAbd': 1}
>   output: ['Aqp', 'Iasd', 'IAbd', 'Aqp', 'Iasd', 'Aqp', 'Aqp', 'Aqp', 'Iasd', 'Iasd', 'Iasd', 'Iasd', 'Iasd', 'Iasd'..., 'Iasd']

```py
def parse_message(string) -> List:
    i, j, ids_map, n, ids = 0, 0, dict(), len(string), ''

    while i < n:
        if string[i] in ('I', 'A') or i == n - 1:
            if ids:
                if i == n - 1:
                    ids_map[ids] = ids_map.get(ids, 0) + int(string[j:])
                else:
                    ids_map[ids] = ids_map.get(ids, 0) + int(string[j:i])
            j = i + 4 if string[i] == 'I' else i + 3
            ids = string[i:j]
            i = j - 1
        i += 1
    res = []
    while any(i > 0 for i in ids_map.values()):
        for k, v in ids_map.items():
            if v > 0:
                res.append(k)
                ids_map[k] -= 1
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one. are you referring to this:

```
import re

def parse_message(string):
    res = list()
    data = re.findall('\d+|\D+', string)
    for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
         for j in range(0, int(data[i+1])):
             res.append(data[i])
    return res
print(parse_message("Aqp1Iasd10Aqp4IAbd1Iasd2"))
```

i use regex to split the string into letters and numbers list, then loop every 2 items ( for string and repition count).